# Easiest method to create pdf from template using command line (without pdflatex)?

Tags: linux, pdf, latex, pdftk

For ten years I have been generating billings for me and my wife in this way:

1. Create TeX template with LyX or by hand
2. Using in this source placeholder text
3. Then:

   ```
   cat template | sed s/placeholder1/somevalue1/ |sed s/placeholder2/somevalue2 ... > output.tex
   pdflatex output.tex
   ```

Sadly in last years this process is becoming more and more difficult because TeX packages are becoming larger and larger (don't know why, but a full TeX installation on Ubuntu is almost 3 GB), and I always get lots of errors in the generation.

So, since I can control all the processes involved, is there a better (easier/more portable) way to create the template and then fill it with fields and create a PDF?

Comment: You don't _need_ a full TeX install, since you are in control of the process, just install the packages you need. How complicated are these PDFs? Do you have multiple images, graphs, links etc? Could we see a sample file? Have you considered using markdown?

Comment: Yes but the packages I need vary from year to year in name, content, and so on. The same packages I installed one or two years ago now are not enough. When I upgrade distro, every single time, there is something that does not work. The files are very simple, table-like, with an image as logo and some basic formatting (right alignment, left, italic, bold...), very simple.

Comment: You could use HTML and then `html2ps` -> `ps2pdf` but LaTeX is probably the best solution.

Comment: Mmmm, at first I did not think at markdown because I started with a Writer (.doc) page, then I switched to LaTeX for flexibility. But... if my pages are so simple, maybe markdown could be the way. I need to find a markdown dialect that supports tables, colour background for tables, and pdf export (or ->html->pdf).

Comment: Well, you could also just generate the HTML and have your browser print to PDF.

Comment: I tried that (html2ps), but it's very uncomfortable, because html2ps retains some aspects of the original page and rejects others, and it's not easy to control output. My page is very simple but I need it to be nicely formatted (fit to page, fit to borders, some double lines for some cells, and so on).

Comment: For what concerns the printing via browser, first of all it's not via command line (i need to do it via command line), second is not so stable because browsers change very fast. I need a method on which I can relay for at least 5-6 years.

Comment: Then you're (probably) stuck with LaTeX. If you use LaTex eclusively for this, I would recommend you don't install the full LaTeX suite but just those few packages you need. That way you don't need to install 3G of data (that's ridiculous, `texlive-base` is only 30M and you should't need much more than that).

Comment: Sorry, but that's not true. Today I installed first of all texlive-base, and it was not enough. Then texlive-recommended, texlive-italian, texlive-greek. And that was not enough. So I installed the *full, and now it works.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12519/discussion-between-terdon-and-d3k)

Comment: Over the last years hard discs have become larger and cheaper and computers have become faster. What exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have seen PDF files generated by using Python and [ReportLab](http://www.reportlab.com/software/opensource/). In the open source version you have to do some programming to get to the output, but there are several examples and this should be straightforward for someone who could handle TeX.

What I have not used but what seems even simpler is to use [rst2pdf](https://rst2pdf.org/). The generating/editing the `.rst` markup format is much the same as using LaTeX.

Comment: I am checking ReportLab and it's a very good solution, stable and complete

Comment: rst2pdf is nice, and does not dipend on latex, just python. I like it. Similar to pandoc+markdown, but pandoc uses latex.

Comment: @d3k I had seen pandoc as well, but did not like the LaTeX dependency. I played a bit with rst2pdf, seems useful, have not touched the include directive which should come in handy instead of using `sed`. Does `rst` give you enough control over the layout?

Answer (score 1):

There is a great TeX alternative called **troff**, it's a standard unix tool and the GNU implementation (**groff**) can be installed into any linux (if it's not already installed).

It's lighweight and fast, can generate html, ps, and pdf.

https://www.gnu.org/software/groff/

https://troff.org/

http://chuzzlewit.co.uk/utp_book-1.1.pdf

By using a groff syntax template file, your command would be:

```
cat template | sed s/placeholder1/somevalue1/ |sed s/placeholder2/somevalue2 ... | groff -T pdf > output.pdf
```

Which is better written as

```
sed -e 's/placeholder1/somevalue1/' \
    -e 's/placeholder2/somevalue2/' \
    -e ...  template |
groff -T pdf > output.pdf
```

If your sed gets too complex, using a template tool like mustache could simplify the task:

http://mustache.github.io/mustache.1.html